# jQuery getting URL Attributes

Tags: jquery

I want to set a few options in a URL and if the URL is set to make something happen, i know how to do this in PHP etc... but never before in jQuery and wondering if it is possible (im sure it is) i want to have a set of links like.....

```
/?banner=banner1
/?banner=banner2
/?banner=banner3
```

Any ideas on how i can say something like `if banner = banner1` do this etc...

im assuming might be using thing like `$.get()` maybe?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this native function to do that:

```
function pget( name ){
  var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
  var regex = new RegExp ( regexS );
  var tmpURL = window.location.href;
  var results = regex.exec( tmpURL );
  if( results == null )
    return "";
  else
    return results[1];
}
```

Name is the name of the parameter (in your case *banner*). If it not exists, the function returns empty string.

I hope it helps.

Regards

Comment: i added function and done console.log(pget()); but shows empty string even when i had ?banner=test in the url? any ideas. thanks for your help btw

Comment: You have to call like this: pget('banner').

Answer (score 1):

You can also use as

```
 var url = "http://example.com/?banner=banner1";
 var pieces = url.split("/?");

 // pieces[0] == "banner=banner1"
```

use as you want then.

Answer (score 0):

I think that has been covered a lot of times : https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=jquery+get+url+parameters

Answer (score -1):

You should use function `.attr( 'href' )`

For example:

```
if( $( 'a.first' ).attr( 'href' ) == $( 'a.second' ).attr( 'href' ) ){

};
```